# How to set specific BottomNavigation Menu Fragment after redirecting from an Activity

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity, bottomnavigationview

In my app, I have many menus. Example A Fragment, B Fragment, C Fragment, & D Fragment. This all are the Bottom Navigation menu. So, my question is how do I get back to one of this particular Fragment of BottomNavigation.

Example: I have selected menu A, now Fragment A is live, there I have some object, I have seleted the Object and now I am redirected to the Object Activity. Now, here in Object Activity I have a back button, so when I click on this back button I want to go back to Fragment A not the default home menu of BottomNavigation, I want to be redirected to where this Object was displaying which is Fragment A.

So, how can I do that. Any solution for that.

I have tried by passing extra from Object Activity, and receiving on HomeActivity where the BottomNavigation is setup.

```
if(getIntent().getExtras.get("FUN").toString.equals(null){
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.nav_graph_fragment,new WineShopFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commitNow();

        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.wineShopFragment);
```

In this way, it works but after running, it thus goes back to the Fragment A, however, when I select the Fragment B or Fragment c or Fragment D, the Content of Fragment A also gets display along with the other selected Fragment. If I select Fragment B after that the Fragment A and B will display together overlapping the display content.

So, can anyone tell me how can I do it successfully without the error mentioned above?

Comment: Add fragmentA in backstack and when you press back button pop it back

Comment: I mean not the default back key, I am indicating to the one I have added in the layout. The default back key works as intended there is no issue with that.

Comment: Put your code of back press

Comment: Here is the code:
`backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {           
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {              
Intent intent= new Intent(editItem.this, HomePage.class);      
intent.putExtra("FRAGMENT",itemTree);                                       
startActivity(intent);                             
}`

Comment: Check out my answer

Answer (score 0):

Please add `addToBackStack()` method in fragment

```
if(getIntent().getExtras.get("FUN").toString.equals(null){
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.nav_graph_fragment,new WineShopFragment());
        fragmentTransactin.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commitNow();

        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.wineShopFragment);
}
```

Add `popBackStack()` method in backpress click in object activity rather than calling intent of homePage

```
public void backPressClick(){
        //this will pop the last added fragment which is fragmentA in your case
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().popBackStack();
}
```